# Rewrite callback URLs in post data using Nginx

Tags: nginx

We are sending post data to an external service with an asynchronous api which requires a callback url as part of the post.

Rather than keep that url as a config item that must be maintained in multiple places, we would like to control where the callback is sent via the nginx config of the relevant environment.

For example, we'd like to rewrite every occurrence of `http://callback.local` to `http://callback.external.com` in the post we're sending out.

Is there a way to do this in nginx?

Comment: You have to keep this configuration somewhere, and your application is really the best place to do it.

Comment: In a distributed system, the application is really not the best place to do it.